# Bound on the covariance of a sum

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, covariance

### Problem

Consider $N$ random variables $X_1,\, \dots,\, X_N \in \mathbb{R}^d$. They are assumed zero-mean, i.e, $\text{E} \left(X_i\right) = 0$, and their covariances are denoted $\text{E}\left[X_i X_i^\intercal\right] = P_i$.
Howerver, the cross-covariances $P_{i,j} = \text{E}\left[X_i X_j^\intercal\right]$ are unknown.

Can we upper-bound the covariance of the sum $S = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$? That is, can we find a covariance $B$ such that,
$$\text{E}\left[S S^\intercal\right] \preceq B,$$
where the inequality is over the set of PSD matrices (Loewner ordering).

### Ideas

Let $C$ denote the covariance of $S$, and introduce the correlation matrices:
$$C = \sum_{1 \le i,j \le n} P_{i,j} = \sum_{1 \le i,j \le n} P^{1/2}_{i} R_{i,j} P^{1/2}_{j}$$.

#### One dimensional

If $d = 1$, $C$ becomes:
$$C =  \sum_{1 \le i,j \le n} \sigma_i \sigma_j \rho_{i,j}.$$
It is clearly maximal when all the correaltions $\rho_{i,j} = 1$. In this case, the optimal bound is $B = (\sum_i \sigma_i)^2$.

Can we extend this kind of reasoning to higher dimensions?

#### Using Covariance Intersection

I known about Covariance Intersection. It provides a bound on the covariance of the augmented vector $X_{aug} = (X_1^\intercal,\, \dots,\, X_N^\intercal)^\intercal$. For any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfying $\theta_i \ge 0$ and $\sum \theta_i =1$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}P_1 & P_{1,2} & \cdots & P_{1,N} \\
P_{2,1} & P_{2} & \cdots & P_{2,N} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots \\
P_{N,1} & P_{N,2} & \cdots & P_N\end{pmatrix} 
\preceq
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\theta_1}P_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{\theta_2} P_{2} & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & \frac{1}{\theta_N}P_N\end{pmatrix}$$

This gives a bound $B = \sum_i \frac{1}{\theta_i}P_i$, in particular $B = N\sum_i P_i$. However, this bound is kind of loose. Can we obtain a tighter bound?